# R packages or open source software for training Hidden Markov chains

Tags: r, machine-learning, data-mining, markov-process, hidden-markov-model

Are there any well-designed R packages or other open-source software for training Hidden Markov chains?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several. For example, (with R) you could use the '[HiddenMarkov](http://cran.at.r-project.org/web/packages/HiddenMarkov/)' package to train and find parameters for HMM models using common algorithms (e.g. Baum-Welch).

There was also a [related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7591311/hidden-markov-models-inplementation-in-r-or-python) on stack overflow, which was apparently closed:

Comment: I would say that without context this question is likely to be voted to close as well.

Comment: I am interested in applying HMM for credit card-related fraud detection. Thanks.

Comment: I found two R-based packages: "HiddenMarkov" and "HMM". Are there any differences between them?

Comment: @user785099 Try both :)